# How to adapt usual method into method of the Class?

Tags: ruby

Need help for beginner(training purpose). For example, I have method custom_uniq and want it to work just like standard .uniq ([1, 2, 1, 3, 3].uniq >> [1,2,3])

```
def custom_uniq(arr)
new_arr = []
  arr.each do |elem|
    new_arr << elem if new_arr.include?(elem) == false
  end
new_arr
end
```

So, what particular part should I modify to insert working method right into Class?

```
class Array
  def custom_uniq
   ?????????
   ????????
  end
end
arr = [1,2,3,1,3,4,5,77]
arr.custom_uniq >> [1,2,3,4,5,77]
```

Comment: Thus is a O(n^2) algorithm (terrible performance).

Comment: Use `unless` instead of `if ... == false` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Array
  def custom_uniq
    new_array = []
    each do |elem| # you call each method on self here
      new_array << elem unless new_array.include?(elem)
    end
    new_array
  end
end
```

Or, as @toro2k suggested, you could make use of [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) method:

```
class Array
  def custom_uniq
    each_with_object([]) do |elem, new_array|
      new_array << elem unless new_array.include? elem
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Although this is correct, I prefer `#reject` as creating the new array explicitly and then having to reference it to return is messier IMO.

Comment: @AaronCronin to be honest, I don't see that superiority.
I think it's okay to leave both answers as alternative.

Comment: You could use `each_with_object` like this: `each_with_object([]) { |elem, new_ary| new_ary << ... }`.

Comment: Your answer is also O(n^2) whilst the reject approach is O(n) (Not that this really matters when writing ruby).

Comment: @AaronCronin I think your answer is O(nlogn). But yes, it's still faster with veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery laaaaaaaaaaaarge sets of data than mine.

Comment: I got the point. Effectiveness of method is a separate issue )

Comment: It's O(n), the check is O(1) and it's executed n times in a linear walk of the original array. I agree with effectiveness though, no point writing harder to understand code just to be marginally faster (especially in Ruby).

Comment: To illustrate... Your solution: `Benchmark.realtime { (1..1000).to_a.lipka_uniq } #=> 0.023271`. My solution: `Benchmark.realtime { (1..1000).to_a.cronin_uniq } #=> 0.000392` I'm not attempting petty point scoring here but growth rates are quite important when replacing standard functions :) (The built-in #uniq takes `0.000224` for reference!)

Comment: @AaronCronin: It matters. In fact, the slower the language, the sooner a O(n^2) will bit you. Writing a simple O(n) algorithm as a O(n^2) is a big no-no.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect use-case for `Array#Reject` and a memory of seen items:

```
class Array
  def custom_uniq
    seen = Hash.new
    reject do |item|
      item_is_duplicate = seen[item] # Check if item has occured already
      seen[item] = true unless item_is_duplicate # Remember seeing new item
      item_is_duplicate # Reject the item from returned array if duplicate
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT: MISC STATS ABOUT RUNTIMES AHEAD...**

I produced the following plot to demonstrate the difference between using a hash-based approach such as this and checking the output array each iteration:

[image: gnuplot]

The code used to generate this plot (43 lines including the definition snippets) is [here](https://gist.github.com/cronin101/6132983).

Comment: +1 The code is still ugly (`reject` is conceptually a functional abstraction while here it also performs side-effects), but well, at least it's O(n). A O(n^2) `uniq` is depressing to see.

Comment: Updated my answer with a graph to illustrate just how depressing it is ;)

Comment: Nice graph. It makes sense, a O(n^2) algorithm gets out of hand very, very fast.